# Compile error: g++-v4/tr1_impl/type_traits(226): error: expected an identifier

Tags: c++, cuda, gpu

The error is generated when a Makefile attempts to compile a .cu (CUDA) file.

We were able to compile this by itself with an .hpp made specifically for it. When we try to get it to compile under an existing header with it's own a .cpp (in other words .hpp, .cpp plus a .cu), we keep getting this strange compilation error.

For the sake of readability, all the follow messages where prefixed with this directory:

```
/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu/4.5.4/include/g++-v4/tr1_impl/
```

Messages:

```
type_traits(226): error: expected an identifier
type_traits(227): error: expected a ")"
type_traits(227): error: a template argument list is not allowed in a declaration of a primary template

type_traits(229): error: expected an identifier
type_traits(230): error: expected a ")"
type_traits(230): error: a template argument list is not allowed in a declaration of a primary template

type_traits(232): error: expected an identifier
type_traits(233): error: expected a ")"
type_traits(233): error: expected a ">"

type_traits(235): error: expected an identifier
type_traits(236): error: expected a ")"
type_traits(236): error: expected a ">"

type_traits(238): error: expected an identifier
type_traits(239): error: expected a ")"
type_traits(239): error: expected a ">"

type_traits(241): error: expected an identifier
type_traits(242): error: expected a ")"
type_traits(242): error: expected a ">"

type_traits(244): error: expected an identifier
type_traits(245): error: expected a ")"
type_traits(245): error: expected a ">"

type_traits(247): error: expected an identifier
type_traits(248): error: expected a ")"
type_traits(248): error: expected a ">"
```

Is it possible to have a single .hpp with a .cu and a .cpp behind it?

Comment: Yes, but if the .hpp includes files that nvcc can't build, then you can't include it from the .cu.  You could use `#ifndef __CUDACC__` around those files so they don't get included when compiling the .cu with nvcc.

Comment: Can you provide a list of the #includes you have in the file that is failing to compile, as well as the compilation command line?

Comment: @harrism - (+1) You are totally right. Make your comment a proper answer and I'll give you the nod.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes it is possible, and in fact very common, but if the .hpp includes files that nvcc can't build, then you can't include it from the .cu.

You could use `#ifndef __CUDACC__` around those files so they don't get included when compiling the .cu with nvcc.